# Oracle SQL: How to create a constraint such that only one row in a group can be 'Checked'

Tags: oracle

In Oracle SQL

Suppose a table with the following structure:

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | ACTIVE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1234567 | Item Desc 1 | Y |
| 2 | A1234567 | Item Desc 2 | N |

I'd like to be able to create a constraint upon this table such that the following operations are allowed:

```
INSERT INTO TBL (name, description, active_flag) VALUES('A1234567', 'Item Desc 3', 'N')
```

```
UPDATE TBL SET active_flag = 'N' WHERE ID = 1
```

but these are is not:

```
INSERT INTO TBL (name, description, active_flag) VALUES('A1234567', 'Item Desc 3', 'Y')
```

```
UPDATE TBL SET active_flag = 'Y' WHERE ID = 2
```

Essentially, I'm interested in a constraint such that for all rows which share a value for `NAME`, only one of those rows can have their active flag set to 'Y'

How might one go about achieving such a constraint?

Comment: Consider that with such a constraint the order in which records are updated matters. You first will have to uncheck a record before you check any other record. This might be a problem if you want to save a bunch of changes with EF's `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional index here. Something like below should work for you -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_UNQ_NAME ON YOUR_TABLE(CASE WHEN ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' 
                                                         THEN NAME
                                                    ELSE NULL
                                               END);
```